# How is the point symmetry group of real space related to the reciprocal space?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, symmetry, crystals

I am taking a course of solid state physics. My teacher asked me that. I have been looking for the answer in the book Solid State Physics by Ashcroft & Mermin, and also in the book of Ibach & Lüth (with the same title). No success.

Comment: Knowledge of point symmetry group allows us to reduce the Brillouin zone to the irreducible Brillouin zone (IBZ). Many interesting physics can be analyzed by studying only a few points of IBZ called high symmetry points. Please take a look at this post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/255058/notations-for-high-symmetry-points-in-the-1st-brillouin-zone

Comment: Perhaps start smaller - what can you say about how the real space representation of a Bravais lattice is related to the reciprocal space representation?